# How to detect manual time change from application even if it is killed

Tags: ios, objective-c, datetime

I have a requirement where I need to detect if date/time has been changed manually from the device settings. I know I can detect the change using `applicationSignificantTimeChange` method, but for that the application needs to be suspended in backgrund. My requirement is that, I need to detect time change even if the application is killed (not running). Any ideas on how to achieve that ?

Note: The application is complete offline with no options to sync with any external time server.

Comment: I don't know what to think about requirements like "what app should do when it is not running" :>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can detect whether the time has been put *backwards* by storing a timestamp whenever your app is suspended, and comparing it with the current time when resuming.

However, this will not work when the time has been put *forwards*. Unfortunately there is no reliable way to detect when the date/time has been manually changed by a user unless you're able to sync your app with a network timestamp (i.e, you have your own server you can request the current time from).

Comment: i'd store seconds from gmt and compare it with the server time of some open time server!?

Comment: Yes - if you have an external source of accurate time you can adequately gauge how much time has *actually* passed since your app was last used, and how much time the system *says* has passed (which, if the user has changed their time settings, will be different)

Comment: If you don't have any way to externally verify time then you can't detect a manual time change where the clock has been set forward. It's just not possible without an external reference - there are no APIs in iOS to do what you're looking for.